Random Forest: Good MSE and R2 but poor cross-validation results
I build, preprocess and clean (na/0s, winsorise, log, etc...) some features and standardise them, using a standard scaler.
If I compute a baseline MSE using just the mean I get 8.22
A simple linear regression yields an MSE of 7.15 and R2 of 0.13
A random forest model with 20 estimators yields an MSE of 3.07 and R2 of 0.62 - which seems strange.
So I tried a k-fold cross-validation using the same random forest model, and get some pretty awful results:
Cross-Validation Scores: [ 0.02259823 -0.70599662 -0.12186488 -0.18245173 -0.33035053]
Mean CV Score: -0.2636131047737679
Standard Deviation of CV Scores: 0.24849696694857612

What should I be looking at to troubleshoot my model at this stage? Not sure which avenue to go down.

If the MSE and R2 is on the training set, the model is probably overfitting.  Out of sample performance estimates, e.g. cross-validation, are (almost) always more reliable.  Or it could be that you have made a mistake in the code (that is always my first assumption when I get surprising results).  What is the performance metric you are using with the cross-validation?

I'm using the default cross_val_score method associated with RF Regressor, which I assume to be R2. The high performance is on the RF model just splitting my data with train_test_split, leaving 20% for the test. Which is why I'm so suprised to see it perform so poorly in x-validation.

I find a default of 100 regressors tends to do substantially better than 20.  What can you tell us about the inputs, outputs, and shape of the data?  I have no framework to understand how much better a 7 is than an 8.  Could you share some code, or pseudo-code so we can know which libraries you are using and how you are using them?  Thanks.
